# Scala - State in closure / anonymous function

Tags: scala, closures, state

I'm trying to take elements from a list while a specific predicate is satisfied. The predicate however depends on the last element. This is
some code illustrating the problem and my solution

```
val list = List(1,2,3,1,4)
list.takeWhile {
   // state inside the closure?!
   var curr = 0

   // actual function application
   i => 
   val test = i > curr
   // update state
   curr = i
   test
}
```

Result as expected is

```
List(1,2,3)
```

However I'm not sure if this works by accident or if this is
intentional by scala. Is there a better way of doing this?

thanks,
Muki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curr` is not "inside the closure". The concept is called "closure" because the anonymous function

```
i => 
  val test = i > curr
  curr = i
  test
```

is an open expression (it has a free variable `curr`) which is *closed* by binding `curr` to the `var` that is declared *outside* of the function.

The bracketed block is not the function passed to `takeWhile` – It is an expression that evaluates to the function.

Answer (score 3):

There's not actually anything in the contract for `takeWhile` that specifies the order in which operations are applied.

Here's a reason not to rely on mutation:

```
scala> def f(list: collection.GenSeq[Int]) = list.takeWhile {
     |    // state inside the closure?!
     |    var curr = 0
     | 
     |    // actual function application
     |    i => 
     |    val test = i > curr
     |    // update state
     |    curr = i
     |    test
     | }
f: (list: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int])scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]

scala> f(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
res22: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int] = ParVector()

scala> f(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
res23: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int] = ParVector(1, 2)
```

This is one those functions you could express as a fold, but you'd usually code it as an imperative loop and name it `takeMonotonically`.

But as an exercise:

```
scala> def f(xs: collection.GenSeq[Int]) = xs.foldLeft(List[Int](),false) {
     | case ((Nil,_),i) => (i::Nil,false)
     | case ((acc,done),i) if !done && acc.head < i => (i::acc,false)
     | case ((acc,_),_) => (acc,true)
     | }
f: (xs: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int])(List[Int], Boolean)

scala> f(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10))
res24: (List[Int], Boolean) = (List(3, 2, 1),true)

scala> f(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
res25: (List[Int], Boolean) = (List(3, 2, 1),true)

scala> f(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
res26: (List[Int], Boolean) = (List(3, 2, 1),true)

scala> def g(xs: collection.GenSeq[Int]) = f(xs)._1.reverse
g: (xs: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int])List[Int]

scala> g(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
res27: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

As a further exercise:

```
object Test extends App {
  def takeMonotonically[R](xs: collection.GenTraversableLike[Int,R]) = {
    val it = xs.toIterator
    if (it.isEmpty) Nil
    else {
      var last = it.next
      val b = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()
      b append last
      var done = false
      while (!done && it.hasNext) {
        val cur = it.next
        done = cur <= last
        if (!done) b append cur
      }
      b.result
    }
  }
  implicit class `gentrav take mono`[R](private val xs: collection.GenTraversableLike[Int,R]) extends AnyVal {
    def takeMonotonically[R] = Test.takeMonotonically(xs)
  }
  Console println takeMonotonically(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10))
  Console println List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).takeMonotonically
  Console println takeMonotonically(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
  Console println takeMonotonically(List(1,2,3,1,4,8,9,10).par)
}
```

or come to think of it:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,4,8,9,10).par.iterator.sliding(2).takeWhile(vs => vs(0) < vs(1)).toList
res0: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4), List(4, 5), List(5, 6))

scala> val end = res0.last(1)
end: Int = 6

scala> (res0 map (_(0))) :+ end
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: This definitely makes one wonder why one would want to ever take a `GenSeq` instead of a `Seq`, since the idea of a `Seq` is to be in order, and the idea of `Gen` is to not necessarily be.  Just take `Seq`, and make anyone with a `GenSeq` do a `.seq` on the way in, no?

Comment: @RexKerr Nobody says the order of ops for takeWhile is defined for any collection, although one assumes for a sequential seq. But I could imagine a sorted seq where that doesn't hold because the predicate is tested at inner nodes while descending a tree.

Comment: Something may not be promised, but still violate the principle of least surprise, which I would argue is the case here.  For instance, the API promises that reverseIterator iterates in reverse order, and that reverse.iterator is the same as reverseIterator, but nowhere does it actually promise that a bare .iterator is in the same order as apply(i); i += 1. This does not mean it would be fun to work with a Seq where you have to reverse it at least once for apply(0) == .iterator.next to be true (on a nonempty collection). However, at least with takeWhile, one should only be a _little_ surprised.